# fixed height div below relative div within relative encompassing div

Tags: css

I have a div container defined as below and have been trying to come up with a setting that allow the bottom "bar" to be a fixed sized and the "grid" section to take the rest no matter the size of the total area.

The closest I got was with `position:fixed`, however the bar was sort of detached, hovering above as the total area got smaller. I want it still be attached right after the grid.

Other settings work fine when the total area is fairly large, however with small sizes, the bar is a mere sliver, since it is only allotted 5%.

```
var sContainer = "<div id='paging_container_{0}' style='position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: #B5CDE4 1px solid;'>".format(oTabProps.ID);
sContainer += "<div id='gridbox_{0}' style='width:100%; height:95%; background-color:white;overflow:auto'></div>".format(oTabProps.ID);
sContainer += "<div id='recinfoArea_{0}' style='overflow: auto;width:100%;height:30px;position:absolute;'></div>".format(oTabProps.ID);
sContainer += "</div>";
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant markup and maybe create a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what is is worth, I added the following to the "bar" container, seems to do what I want, it's always 30px high at the bottom

```
position: absolute;bottom: 0; overflow: auto;width:100%
```